# OData join in a many to many

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-core-odata

I have a many-to-many relation

```
class User 
{
    int Id { get; }
    int Name { get; }

    List<UserClass> UserClasses { get; }
}

class Class
{
    int Id { get; }
    int Name { get; }

    List<UserClass> ClassUsers { get; }
}

class UserClass
{
    int UserId { get; }
    User User { get; }

    int ClassId { get; }
    Class Class{ get; }
}
```

And am trying to create a query which will fetch me a grouping of classes per user, the result should be something like this

```
[
  {
      UserId: '1',
      Classes: [{
         Name: 'c1',
      },{
         Name: 'c2',
      },{
         Name: 'c3',
      },{
         Name: 'c4',
      }],          
  },
  {
      UserId: '2',
      Classes: [{
         Name: 'c2',
      },{
         Name: 'c7',
      }],          
  },
]
```

Comment: That seems like a strange design. If anything, `User` should have a `List<Class> Classes` and `Class` should have a `List<User> Users`, and `UserClass` would only have `UserId` and `ClassId`. Isn't it problematic to have a `User` contain a list of themselves (i.e. `User.UserClasses` is a list of objects that all contain the same `User` object)? It looks to me like every item in `UserClasses` will have a `UserClass.User` property that will then have it's own list of `UserClasses`, and so on, until you get a stack overflow?

Comment: You want `Courses` in the response, but there is no mention of this in your schema example. We can assume you mean `Class` or `Classes` but that would make an Ass of U and Me ;)

Comment: Looks like the EF *Core* model was exposed through OData without cleaning it up. OData isn't EF, or an HTTP API for EF. The OData model should make sense by itself - a `User` has `Classes`. In EF 6 and EF Core 5 there's no need to expose the many-to-many table in the model.

Comment: You could upgrade to EF Core 5 and [remove the join table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many) altogether

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes will do that, seems that this should solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your model isn't exposed as `User` having a `List<Class> Classes` then you will need to keep the junction object in the query.

`Users?$select=UserId&$expand=UserClasses($expand=Class($select=Name))`

should return

```json
[
  {
    "UserId": "1",
    "UserClasses": [
      {
        "Class": { "Name": "c1" }
      },
      {
        "Class": { "Name": "c2" }
      },
      {
        "Class": { "Name": "c3" }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "UserId": "2",
    "UserClasses": [
      {
        "Class": { "Name": "c1" }
      },
      {
        "Class": { "Name": "c4" }
      },
    ]
  }
]
```